After ranaming package in android studio from com.example.travelapp to com.company.travelapp i get the error: RuntimeException, NoClassDefFoundError
I'm encountering a NoClassDefFoundError related to androidx.lifecycle.ReportFragment$ActivityInitializationListener in my Android application, resulting in a fatal exception that causes the app to crash immediately upon launch. Here is the full stack trace:
                         java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider androidx.startup.InitializationProvider: androidx.startup.StartupException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/lifecycle/ReportFragment$ActivityInitializationListener;
                            at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:7642)
                            …
                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1011)
                         Caused by: androidx.startup.StartupException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/lifecycle/ReportFragment$ActivityInitializationListener;
                            at androidx.startup.AppInitializer.doInitialize(AppInitializer.java:187)
                            …
                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1011)
                         Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/lifecycle/ReportFragment$ActivityInitializationListener;
                            at androidx.lifecycle.ProcessLifecycleInitializer.create(ProcessLifecycleInitializer.kt:37)
                            …
                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1011)
                         Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.lifecycle.ReportFragment$ActivityInitializationListener" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~ohF60lMUCczmAb5rmHzgvw==/com.company.travelapp-g88i1O-Z7OUyKk4cvThJVA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~ohF60lMUCczmAb5rmHzgvw==/com.company.travelapp-g88i1O-Z7OUyKk4cvThJVA==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system/system_ext/lib64]]
                            at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:207)
                            …
                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1011)

Steps I've Tried

Updated Dependencies: Ensured all lifecycle and startup dependencies are up-to-date in build.gradle.

Cleaned and Rebuilt Project: Performed clean and rebuild steps in Android Studio.

Checked ProGuard Rules: Added rules to keep all necessary classes.

Cleared Gradle Cache: Removed the Gradle cache to resolve any potential corruption issues.

Manually Verified Class: Attempted to verify the presence of the class in the JAR files.


build.gradle (app level) Configuration
dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-process:2.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.startup:startup-runtime:1.1.0'
}

android {
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

ProGuard Rules
-keep class androidx.lifecycle.** { *; }
-keep class androidx.startup.** { *; }


I had the same problem and exception when upgrading my "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.5.1" to version "...:2.8.3" (actually all "...:2.8.X" versions) and as a workaround I'm now using version: "implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.7.0")".

2.7.0 is working fine, any version in 2.8.x will produce the same error

Helo, if you are using viewModel make sure you have this versions:
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.6.2'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.6.2'

Thats actually works!!

2.7.0 is also working, seems to be the broplem is in 2.8.x

This issue is resolved in the newer AGP versions, i've tested it on 8.6.0 and someone in the issue https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/341688001 says it's working on 8.5.1

My project stopped working after a update of lifecycle Livedata Ktx and lifecycleViewmodelKtx
If you are using build.gradle.kts, go to file libs.versions.toml and change the versions of lifecycleLivedataKtx and lifecycleViewmodelKtx to the ones below:
 lifecycleLivedataKtx = "2.7.0" 
 lifecycleViewmodelKtx = "2.7.0"

If using the Java version of build.gradle, use this:
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.7.0' 
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.7.0'

*Versions 2.8.x, are causing the error for me
